# Scroll Magic content height

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I have problem with my site.. I am trying to modify this example from scroll magic website: http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/basic/section_wipes_natural.html

only differencce is that some sections are heigher than view port height and content in them is cut down, nex section enters to early... Can any one tell me how can I force ScrollMagic to show whole content of those elements?

Comment: without seeing the modifications you've made to working code, how can anyone show you what you did wrong?

Comment: Ok sorry here is plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bXGQmoCvXdl2fjjIhOEV?p=preview